# Raspberry Pi Zero w two UARTs

Tags: usb, pi-zero, uart

I use on my RPi Zero UART ports on GPIO 14&15 on device `/dev/ttyS0`, and that is ok.

But I need another UART port, can I connect to micro USB port on board USB-UART converter CP2102 to get the second UART on `/dev/ttyGS0`?

Answer (score 1):

Quick soloution when I connect USB-uart to micro usb port I have `/dev/ttyUSB0` port and thats it.